# find matching words and underline them - but just the words

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have this code where I'm trying to search and underline all instances of a specified word:

```js
$(".test:contains('moon')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">The cow jumped over the moon</div>
```

The above is underlining the whole text.

How can I get it to underline just the instances of "moon"?

Comment: you need to define each word in seprate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, you are applying the style to the whole `element` that contains the searched `word`.

You need to loop through all the matched words and replace them accordingly with the desired style in the `html` of the containing `element`:

```js
let word = 'moon';

$(".test:contains('" + word + "')").each(function() {
  let regex = new RegExp("(" + word + ")", 'g');
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">$1</span>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">The cow jumped over the moon</div>
```

Comment: How can I change this example to read a variable instead of hardcoded text?

Comment: @urhen2019 I updated the snippet to fit that, you just need to define a new `RegExp` object.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over each element and `.replace` its `innerHTML`:

```js
$(".test:contains('moon')").each(function() {
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/moon/g, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">moon</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">The cow jumped over the moon</div>
```

Comment: Then just do the same sort of thing, only the other way around - replace `<span style...` with just `moon`

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui what about it? The OP made no mention of it, nor is it implied that there is any dynamic user input. The example is using a static value to search for.